# How do I change the value of a string with the output of a file between the start of <x> and the end of <y>

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to set the value of a string, `OUTPUT`, to some text in a file. Basically in the file, I want to set the value of `OUTPUT` with all the text between two strings `TRACE,0000` & `,Time,0`

For example:

`random text in the file`

`random text in the file`

`random text in the file`

`TRACE,0000`

`stuff`

`goes`

`in`

`here`

`Time,0`

`random text in the file`

`random text in the file`

`random text in the file`

And the value of `OUTPUT` to be:

`TRACE,0000`

`stuff`

`goes`

`in`

`here`

`Time,0`

I just don't know how to approach this. If anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: It's just a simple loop. Read the file one line at a time, check each line for the starting and ending values, and if you've found the starting value but haven't yet passed the ending value then add the line to the output. People like to see that you've made some effort, so try coding something along the lines above, and if you get stuck, post your question here with the code you've written so far.

Comment: To be honest this would be easier in a scripting language.

Comment: Issue is that I don't know the beginning of each line, only the beginning and end of the text.

Comment: @john I think the sed command would be `sed -n '/TRACE,0000/,/Time,0/ p'`

Comment: @zjf What do you mean "I don't the beginning of each line"?

Comment: @zjf So you are saying that `TRACE,0000` might not be the whole line? And the same for `Time,0`? That's not clear in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The following sample code may help you. As shown in the code, the checking process will be donw in the `while-loop`. I hope it will help you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    // other things to do
    std::fstream readFile;
    readFile.open("file");
    if (!readFile.is_open()){
        std::cout<<"Files couldn't be open!";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line = "";
    bool start_read = false;
    while (getline(readFile, line)) {
        if(line == "TRACE,0000")
            start_read = true;
        else if (line == "Time,0"){
            std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
            break;
        }

        if(start_read)
            std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
    }
    // remaining things to do
    return 0;
}
```